# Reading from Datagrid Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Datagrid  , in which there are 3 columns , The values of two columns are fetched from database and populated whereas the third column is a textbox where the user enters the value. i have to save this value into the database . i am facing some problem here .
When i enter the value in the UI , it is showing null in the background code ..What am i doing wrong ?

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="233" Name="dataGrid1" Width="360" > 
   <DataGrid.Columns>

     <DataGridTextColumn Header="x" Binding="{Binding Path=x}" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" />
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="y" Binding="{Binding Path=y}" Width="120"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value/Ref" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=z, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="False" />

     </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I have a class containing variables x,y,z . I am creating a list of the class and trying to add the values to the class

Comment: did you try `Binding="{Binding Path=z, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`?

Comment: Yes , but its not working :(

Comment: Is setter on the z property called? Can you post relevant code? How does the object, that holds x, y and z, looks like?

Comment: Xvalue = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(((DataGridRow)dataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)).Item)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();                                                                                                                                                                              This is how i am reading the values for even y and z  .              x, y , z are string added to a list

Comment: I still don't see definition of object that exposes x, y and z properties that are bound to 3 columns? Is it class or struct? Update your question with that code and other relevant things

Comment: the variables x,y,z are string variables defined inside a class A.I am creating a LIST<A> obj = new LIST<A>();  and i am adding all these values to obj.

Comment: If your `A` is a class, `z` is a public property with a setter and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` then it should work and you should be able to update value of `z` from `DataGrid`. Unfortunately without the code I won't be able to help you more then that.

Answer (score 0):

With your XAML code and this simple code snippet, the behaviour is like you want (what I understand):

```
class A
    {
        private string _x, _y, _z;

        public string x { get { return _x; } set { _x = value; } }
        public string y { get { return _y; } set { _y = value; } }
        public string z { get { return _z; } set { _z = value; } }
    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<A> myData;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myData = new List<A>();
            myData.Add(new A() { x = "x1", y = "y1" });
            myData.Add(new A() { x = "x2", y = "y2" });
            myData.Add(new A() { x = "x3", y = "y3" });

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myData;
        }
    }
```

If you type in any data in column Value/Ref, the List behind is definitely updated.